# How to find a max of a certain matrix

Tags: matrix

find the Max of the numbers found in the 2nd entry of these lists. Also  give its Position:

Ex : {1 2 3 4 5} {1 3 4 5 6} {2 5 5 5 5}  This is a 1,3 Matrix , and we want to get the highest number of the second entry so out of 2 3 and 5

Comment: That sure looks like a 3 by 5 matrix, if you add in the commas. Call it mat. Then you can get the entries you want by: Transpose[mat][[2]]

Answer (score 2):

```
matrix = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 5, 5, 5}};
matrix[[All, 2]]
(* {2, 3, 5} *)

Max[matrix[[All, 2]]]
(* 5 *)
```