# How to solve for a Diff Eq?

Tags: differential-equations

Solve the differential equation y'(x) + x * y(x) = 0, where y(0) = 3.
Show your solution is correct; that is, plug it back into the original
DE and show it works.

Comment: This is the second question ([first one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204805/58370)) you have asked that looks like a homework problem. Your are unlikely to get answers to any future questions unless you share your attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To solve ODE, the command is called `DSolve`

```
ode = y'[x] + x*y[x] == 0;
ic = y[0] == 3;
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To verify the solution, help recommends using `y` instead of `y[x]` in the above call, like this

```
ode = y'[x] + x * y[x] == 0;
ic = y[0] == 3;
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now you can verify the solution using

```
ode /. sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since the result is true, it means the solution satisfies the ODE.

There are lots of examples in the `DSolve` help page.

Comment: My favorite line in my solutions, that I was told to use in QM was “used Mathematica”—I wonder how “asked Nasser” would fly? Probably better than what I used before “used Mathematica”: “...and then some magic happened”— +1 to ya, Nasser!